# How to list the AWS instance id in Resource group

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-resource-group

I am trying to get the EC2 InstanceId in my resource group(hello-rg). Here is my code:

````
client = boto3.client('resource-groups', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id="key", aws_secret_access_key="id")

response = client.list_group_resources(
    GroupName='hello-rg',
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'resource-type',
            'Values': [
                'instance',
            ]
        },
    ],
)

print(response) ```


I am getting the error:
````

File "rg.py", line 21, in 
'instance',
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ListGroupResources operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '[instance]' at 'filters.1.member.values' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 128, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1, Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: AWS::[a-zA-Z0-9]+::[a-zA-Z0-9]+] ```

Comment: Looks like you left off the error message....Please edit your response and include the error message you're getting...

Answer (score 1):

I know it is already too late. But this might help others

As the error indicates, `Values` need to be a list of strings, matching the regex pattern `AWS::[a-zA-Z0-9]+::[a-zA-Z0-9]+]`. For getting the instances, the Value string has to be `['AWS::EC2::Instance']`

Something like this should work

```py
response = client.list_group_resources(
    GroupName='hello-rg',
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'resource-type',
            'Values': [
                'AWS::EC2::Instance',
            ]
        },
    ],
)
```